# Operation not supported on read-only collection c# wp7

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, windows-phone-7

Im trying to implement a lazy "load more" items when the user gets to the bottom of the listbox, but everytime i try to add new items to the listbox i get results like this:

**"Operation not supported on read-only collection."**

I've already tried several solutions from forums to blogs none seem to work. I can't even understand the logic behinds the problem which seems a bit odd for me.

What i'm doing is basically loading a list of items and assigning as the itemsource of my listbox.

```
  wineFilterListBox.ItemsSource = wines;
```

When the user gets to the bottom of the list, i add more items (just like twitter app for wp7)

```
public ObservableCollection<Wine> wines;
...

   if (atBottom)
   {
       int Count = page.wineFilterListBox.Items.Count;
       int end = Count + 10;
       for (int i = Count; i < end; i++)
       {
           page.LoadWineList(Count);
       }
   }
...

   private void LoadWineList(int Count = 1)
   {
   ...
      wineFilterListBox.Items.Add(wines);
   }
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you use `ItemSource` the `Items` collection becomes read-only.  It sounds like you'd have to add the data to the collection instead of to the `ListBox` `Items` property.

See the MSDN: [ItemsControl.ItemSource Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemssource.aspx)

In particular, this section:

> When the ItemsSource property is set, the Items collection is made read-only and fixed-size.

Try adding the item to the `wines` collection directly, since your collection is an `ObservableCollection':

> You should set the ItemsSource to an object that implements the
>   INotifyCollectionChanged interface so that changes in the collection
>   will be reflected in the ItemsControl. The ObservableCollection(Of T)
>   class defines such an object.

Comment: thanks. Removing the last line did it. 
"wineFilterListBox.Items.Add(wines);"

I tried so many solutions that i missed the basic while using ObservableCollection. Just adding to the wines list was enough to update the listbox.

Comment: @BrunoNunes: No problem!  It's always the little things that get us :-)

Answer (score 0):

FYI, if you intentionally dont want to use `ObservableCollection` to set `ItemsSource`
You can add `Wine` manually to your `wineFilterListBox.Items`

```
for (int i = Count; i < 10; i++)
{
    wineFilterListBox.Items.Add(new Wine());
}
```

This cause the `wineFilterListBox.Items` to not become read-only